# Is there an R function to subtract two date time data?

Tags: r, time, difftime, timedate

I have two columns of data that are dttm that I'm trying to get the difference from to then get the total average.

Essentially I have a start time to a trip, an end time. I'd like to know the difference between them and then get the average time that produces, but difftime() isn't working. Any ideas on what function to use for two dttm to return a value in hours, min, sec?

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1, tz = tz) :
> do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”

This error is thrown when I try to enter just the difftime(ended_at,started_at)

```
cyclistic_data %>% 
  group_by(member_casual) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  summarise(av_member_ride_time = mean(difftime(ended_at,started_at)))
```

EDIT: I may have found a way to achieve what I want out of that one line anyways.

```
cyclistic_data %>% 
  reframe(av_member_ride_time = mean(as_hms(difftime(started_at, ended_at))))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "isn't working" - is it throwing an error, not giving you results you want? If you could edit your question to make this reproducible, that would likely get you better, faster help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jabe! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add the output of dput(cyclistic_data) to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI, `mean` has an `na.rm` argument rather than using `drop_na` (unless of course you are doing other summary tasks where you need `NA` dropped).

Comment: As an aside, never call the `.default()` fallback but rather the generic, here `as.POSIXct()` so that proper dispatching based on the argument type can occur.

Comment: Thank you for all the notes, definitely helped on other issues I didn't realize I had. I think I figured out how to get it to work and updated the post

Comment: Change your update to your post above to an answer, as they (answers) tend to be looked at first by other searchers, then accept your answer. It would also be preferable to (above) `dput` sufficient data that future searchers may compare their situation to what you've solved.